# Conversão de Float para Array de Byte

Tags: java, array, float

Como posso estar realizando a conversão de `float` ou inteiro (se isso for possível) para um *array* de byte em Java.

Digamos:

```
float x=180
```

Teoricamente precisaria criar 1 *array* de bytes com 2 posições. Existe alguma forma de 'automatizar' isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(180).array();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/FromFloat.java).

Isto criaria um *array* com 4 posições. Os bytes isoladamente não servirão para muita coisa.

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). Ali mostra os métodos para lidar com os outro tipos que possa querer. O que esta classe faz é justamente tratar o dado como se fossem apenas bytes.